No output from the Interceptor when using InterceptorBinding
I am learning Interceptor Binding using annotations. The version is Java 11, and Jakarta EJB 4. The server is GlassFish 7. There is no deployment descriptor and annotations archive all requirements.
I have added a print statement to see whether it's working. But, there is no output in the server log. Here is the code.
Auth.java
package com.aadhil.ejb.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

import jakarta.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
public @interface Auth {
}

AuthInterceptor.java
package com.aadhil.ejb.interceptor;

import com.aadhil.ejb.annotation.Auth;
import jakarta.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import jakarta.interceptor.Interceptor;
import jakarta.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Auth
@Interceptor
public class AuthInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object authenticate(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Auth Interceptor");
        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
}

LoginImpl.java
package com.aadhil.ejb.impl;

import com.aadhil.ejb.annotation.Auth;
import com.aadhil.ejb.entity.User;
import com.aadhil.ejb.remote.Login;
import jakarta.ejb.Stateless;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.NoResultException;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Auth
@Stateless
public class LoginImpl implements Login {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public User login(String email, String password) {
        try {
            return em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username=:username AND u.password=:password", User.class)
                    .setParameter("username", email)
                    .setParameter("password", password)
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

When using @Interceptors annotation in the session bean class and @AroundInvoke annotation in the interceptor class, it worked fine. But, when trying with a custom annotation class with @InterceptorBinding annotation, I cannot see any log. I also added the @Inherited annotation to my custom annotation. But I got the same result. My tutor does not use the @Inherited annotation or any XML file to configure the interceptors.

Can you try adding @Priority with a valid value (e.g. @Priority(1000)) on the interceptor?

@NikosParaskevopoulos I tried with the @Priority and it works! But I cannot understand why it doesn't work without @Priority.

As commented, you need to define the @Priority(int value) annotation on the interceptor. The reason is a bit hidden in the specifications.
If you take a look at the relevant specification (currently Jakarta Interceptors 2.2), chapter 3.4 "Interceptor Resolution", it says:

An interceptor is bound to a method or constructor if:

[...]
The interceptor is enabled. An interceptor is enabled if the Priority annotation is applied to the
interceptor class. An extension specification may define other means of enabling interceptors.
For example, the CDI specification enables an interceptor if the interceptor class is listed under
the <interceptors> element of the beans.xml file for the bean archive.


